# how to calculate score quiz in js?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];
```

I wrote a function named `scoreQuiz`:

```
function scoreQuiz(responses, score) {
  var num=score;

  if(num==score) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

It takes two arguments:

- `responses` - An array of all of the responses for a given person, and
- `score` - A decimal number representing the minimum score needed to pass the quiz.

It should return a Boolean value that represents whether or not the student passed the quiz.

For example:

```
scoreQuiz(responses, 0.8);  //> false
scoreQuiz(responses, 0.75); //> true
scoreQuiz(responses, 0.7);  //> true
```

I'm getting true returned correctly but for some reason its not returning false.
Can someone please help?

Comment: In scoreQuiz, why are you setting a variable `num` to equal to the argument `score`? This is always going to return true because `num` is always going to equal `score`.

Comment: do you understand the question ? i cant figure out what I'm supposed to compare the score too

Comment: No, that wasn't clear at all. Please update your question to reflect that's what you're missing. You have to loop through the responses array and count how many times you see `response: true` then once you have that, you can compare the correct answers to your minimum requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your code to work you will have to update it as follows with comments:

```
// changed score to minScoreToPass to be more descriptive. 
function scoreQuiz(responses, minScoreToPass) {
  // here I'm using reduce method to calculate the score for the responses. 
  const score = responses.reduce((val, item) => {
    return item.isCorrect ? val += 1 : val;
  }, 0)
  // here you have to compare the score in decimal form so I divide by the total questions to get the percentage/decimal and compare to minScoreToPass
  if (score/responses.length >= minScoreToPass) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Please review reduce method if needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

```js
const responses = [
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];

console.log( scoreQuiz(responses, 0.8)); //> false
console.log( scoreQuiz(responses, 0.75)); //> true
console.log( scoreQuiz(responses, 0.7)); //> true

function scoreQuiz(responses,score){
const pointsForEachQuestion = 1/responses.length;
let userScore=0
responses.map(item=> {
if(item.isCorrect){
 userScore += pointsForEachQuestion
}
})
if(userScore<score){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

You question is not clear enough but this what you are after I believe.

Your total mark is 1 so for each correct ans user will get `pointsForEachQuestion = 1/responses.length`. Now you have to go through the responses array and check for all the correct ans and if the ans is correct you have to add`userScore` by `pointsForEachQuestion` . In the end return true or false by comparing `userScore` and `score`.